# Unity - Is there a way to programmatically call Fire2 on Input Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using C# and DF-GUI. I wanted to see if there is a way to have a df gui button programmatically call fire2 (alt) on input manager. I thought this would be pretty easy but I haven't found anything on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling fire2 from code. You can call the method inside fire2 from code. That will be easy and not confusing.

```
void Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetButton("Fire2"))
    {
        Fire();
    }

    if(FireCondition)
    {
        Fire ();
        FireCondition=false;
    }
}

void Fire ()
{
    //Do what you want here
}
```